# Sending MMI codes from bash script

Tags: bash, mobile, gsm, ussd, gammu

I am trying to make a little bash script that will activate call forwarding to some number on some condition using mobile broadband dongle connected to the usb port.
I can easily send sms messages, call USSD codes using either mmcli (ubuntu) or gammu, but I cannot run MMI codes. These codes have very similar syntax to USSD but [are not the same](https://berlin.ccc.de/~tobias/mmi-ussd-ss-codes-explained.html).

Can I send MMI codes using any command line tool? If yes - how?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage call forwarding directly by Gammu, see http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/#cmdoption-gammu-arg-divert

Comment: It's not working for me for some reason. Any other way?

Comment: Not using Gammu, you can check logs to see what's wrong: http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/